# The images should loop when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following function to loop to the next image once '>' button is clicked. Is it possible to use the same function to ensure that the images move to the next one once the image itself is clicked at any area?

```
function nextPic(){
                count = parseInt(count) +1;
                if(parseInt(count)>9) 
                    count=1;
                    $( "#largeImg").fadeOut(0);
                    document.getElementById('largeImg').src="Original/0" + count + ".jpg";
                    $( "#largeImg").fadeIn(0001);
            }
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: why not just call the same function of the click of the `largeImg` element

Comment: @ArunPJohny:well I'm very new to programming. I get what you're saying but I'm not sure how to do it. I do not know how to adjust the html/css part of it. Could you help me please?

Comment: how is `nextPic` called when you click on `>`

Comment: You could also use `count = (count + 1) % 9`, which would eliminate the need for an if statement. Or, you could use `count = ++count % 9`.

Comment: <div id="leftIcon" onClick="prevPic();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div> .. If this is what you mean. @ArunPJohny

Comment: even though I would recommend using inline event handler.... for now add the `onclick="nextPic()"` to your `<img id="largeImg" />`(just for test - you need to have a look at how to use jQuery to register event handlers)

Comment: Oh awesome,this is what I was finding for. Thank you for helping. @ArunPJohny

Comment: Looks to me you could also omit the fadeOut/fadeIn bit (with 0/1 ms, that won't really do anything anyway). By just resetting the element's src attribute you will cause the same effect.

Comment: @christian314159 : Noted but it was done as per requested by my supervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add click event with the image control.

do it as below

```
$('#largeImg').onclick(function(){
  //call you function here
});
```